# DNS record for permanent redirect?

Tags: redirects, dns

Newbie webmaster here: I have 2 domains `example.com` and `example.net`. I want a permanent redirect so that if anyone browses to `example.net` they navigate to `example.com`. Is there a way to do this using DNS records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a CNAME record for your `.net` domain, this way your DNS will translate `example.net` to `example.com`.

Comment: Thanks - so to clarify, I should create a CNAME for "*" that points at "mydomain.com"?  Will that mean that the url will automatically change to mydomain.com?  That's important, because the web server will dish up content according to what URL is requested.

Comment: Unfortunately, users see whatever they typed. The DNS only tells the user where the website is hosted. Since you want a HTTP redirect (like HTTP 301), you should configure that in a virtualhost of some kind

Comment: So DNS can't do an automatic URL rewrite?

Comment: Correct, DNS has nothing to do with HTTP, basicly it only translates between names and IP addresses

Answer (score 4):

You can try http://redirect.center.

In your case, configure your DNS like this:

```
example.net A 54.84.55.102
redirect.example.net CNAME www.example.com.redirect.center
www.example.net CNAME www.example.redirect.center
```

Comment: Interesting idea, and I suppose *.redirect.center will implement http(s) redirects to *.

Comment: Their own website is HTTP only (no HTTPS), so it looks like they are not set up for HTTPS redirects.  There is an option to redirect *to* HTTPS, but users that try to access the redirecting domain through HTTPS will get an error. Any redirect service that wants to do HTTPS redirects [needs to obtain security certificates for each domain being redirected](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/118044/do-i-need-a-certificate-to-redirect-via-cname) and it doesn't look like they are set up to do that.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller: I don't think they would need a security certifificate for each domain, just a wildcard certificate for redirect.center. But good to know that it only works for http, even if that is not good.

Comment: It would actually need a certificate for each domain, otherwise the initial connection to to the redirecting domain to request the redirect wouldn't work.

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller: I don't see why. if you have a wildcard certificate on `*.redirect.center`, and your domain is `example.com.redirect.center` (`*.redirect.center`) you don't need the certificate of example.com to redirect to example.com. The only question is if a wildcard for redirect.center also covers `*.com.redirect.center`. You might need an additional wildcard certificate for `*.com.redirect.center` for example.com.redirect.center to be valid.

Comment: If your redirecting domain is `redirecting.example` which has a CNAME to `example.com.redirect.center` which then redirects that to `http://example.com`, the server for redirect center needs a certificate for `redirecting.example` to enable `https://redirecting.example/` or browsers will show an error during the security handshake when connecting to `example.com.redirect.center`.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to "redirect" using DNS records.

As mentioned:

> You could create a CNAME record for your `.net` domain, this way your
> DNS will translate `example.net` to `example.com`.

This is a good first step, but this only sets the domain to point to the same IP, it doesn't actually perform any redirecting. Once the domain is pointing to the same place you can then set your webserver (Apache/NGINX/IIS/&c) to HTTP redirect traffic from one domain to the other.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do a http-redirect from DNS directly. 
DNS can only resolve DNS names to IPs, it cannot issue http directives.

However, it is possible to use a combination of DNS CNAME entries and a generic redirection application. 
For that, you have to setup an application that accepts requests on an IP or subdomain-IP.

Then you can have a web-application listening on that IP/subdomain-ip.

Then your web-application needs to permanently redirect/forward requests for mydomain.net to mydomain.com.

The generic variant is to have *.somedomain.tld with a wildcard TLS certificate and then read * and then have the http-application on *.somedomain.tdl doing the redirect to * **if * is registered in your redirect database**.

Alternatively, you can setup the application/reverse-proxy on mydomain.com to also accept requests to mydomain.net, **and** have http-url-rewriting in your application, then you can do this with just cname. This will however require you to setup http-url-rewriting which is error-prone, since you need to re-write HTTP-headers, HTML and JSON/XML and whatever else contains formats that contain URLs.

Therefore, it's simpler to have an intermediary application do permanent redirects. 
Please note that hashes in URLs, e.g. the #foo in http(s)://somedomain.com#foo cannot be read on the server side. Any redirects that use hashes need to be forwarded using javascript on the client-side.

So you see, you cannot do this with DNS only directly. 
At the very least it requires CNAME and URL-rewriting ON THE SERVER. 
Doing this CORRECTLY for get/post/other-http-verb requests (in various formats) is NOT trivial, unless you do it incorrectly, in which case it will bite you sooner or later. 
And you can count on the fact that "it" will be sooner, rather than later.
Source: been there done that.