# Do I need a certificate to redirect via CNAME?

Tags: https, security-certificate, cname

I have `abc.example.com` that is being shut down and all data was sent via SSL.

I have `xyz.example.com` already live and pure SSL site.   I am changing record (`CNAME`) for `abc.example.com` to point to `xyz.example.com`.   `xyz.example.com` already has a working cert.   Do I need a cert for traffic originating from `abc.example.com`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you'll still need an SSL certificate for `abc.example.com`

Due to the nature of CNAME redirection, when you type `abc.example.com` in the browser, the URL stays `abc.example.com`, and this is where you need the SSL certificate.

---

**SEO Tips**

You might want to use 301 redirects instead of CNAME redirect, this will pass on the ranking power/juice from `abc.example.com` to `xyz.example.com`.

However, this would still require an SSL certificate.

Have you tried [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) ? a certificate authority that provides free SSL certificate.

Answer (score 23):

[Neverever](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/92955/neverever)'s answer is correct.  You do need an SSL certificate.    I wanted to add that it is because **there is no such thing as a CNAME redirect**.

A CNAME is not a redirect.   A CNAME instructs the DNS to resolve to the same domain as where the CNAME points.   The CNAME does not cause a redirect.  It only causes the HTTP request for a domain to be made to the same IP address as requests for another domain.

The process a browser and operating system actually uses for getting a redirect from `https://site1.example/` to `https://site2.example/` is:

1. DNS lookup for `site1.example`. Discover it it is a CNAME for `site2.example`.
2. DNS lookup for `site2.example`.  Find an `A` record for its IP address (`192.0.2.4`, for example).
3. Open a socket to the IP address `192.0.2.4` on port 443.
4. Negotiate TLS (SSL) for the domain `site1.example`.
5. Make the HTTPS request for `https://site1.example/`:

   ```
   GET / HTTP/1.1
   Host: site1.example
   ```
6. Get the response back with the redirect:

   ```
   301 Moved Permanently
   Location: https://site2.example/
   ```
7. Perform another DNS lookup for `site2.example`.  Find an `A` record for its IP address (`192.0.2.4`, for example).  The DNS response will come from DNS cache this time.
8. Open a socket to the IP address `192.0.2.4` on port 443.
9. Negotiate TLS (SSL) for the domain `site2.example`.
10. Make the HTTPS request for `https://site2.example/`:

    ```
    GET / HTTP/1.1
    Host: site2.example
    ```
11. Get the response back with the content:

    ```
    200 OK
    ...
    ```

Just to be able to redirect a HTTPS request you need DNS for that domain,  a web server for that domain, and SSL for that domain.   It doesn't actually matter if you use a `CNAME` record or an `A` record.  A redirect can happen either way.

In fact, an `A` record is almost always more efficient.   DNS lookups are faster with direct `A` records than with `CNAME` records.   `CNAME` records require a second DNS lookup and don't make the rest of the redirection process easier.

Comment: "DNS lookups are faster with direct A records than with CNAME records." Things are cached, so besides edge cases I think the speed difference, if any, will be negligible after everything else taken into account (time of TLS handshake, time of HTTP headers transmission, etc.). Also with more and more DoT/DoH and web/DNS hosting companies being at the same time public resolvers, there will be shortcuts (it is the exact same discussion currently about "CNAME at apex", if you look at the `ANAME` record the auth server does the recursion before its reply)

Comment: Thank your for making this clear. I've been baffled by this.